# convert all the values in a dictionary to strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, type-conversion

Say I have a mixed list of dictionaries with strings and integers as values and I want to convert the integers to strings, how should one do that without going all over the place and converting them one by one considering that the list is fluid, long and might also change some of the existing values to integers.

**Example:**

```
list = [{'a':'p', 'b':2, 'c':'k'},
        {'a':'e', 'b':'f', 'c':5}]
```

Now if I'll try and print the values of the list with a string it will give me an error as follows.

**Example:**

```
for x in list:
    print('the values of b are: '+x['b'])
```

**Output:**

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

```
list = [{'a':'p', 'b':2, 'c':'k'},
        {'a':'e', 'b':'f', 'c':5}]

for dicts in list:
    for keys in dicts:
        dicts[keys] = str(dicts[keys])
print('the values of b are: '+ dicts["b"])
```

Comment: Would you like the items to permanently be strings? else you could just wrap the x['b'] with ```str(x['b'])```

Comment: thanks mate it worked! my mistake is that I were trying to do it a little bit different before just like this: ```(x[str('b')])```

Comment: Great, let me still point to my Answer, if you need a more general solution to always get a String, no matter, what kind of value was entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
list = [{'a':'p', 'b':2, 'c':'k'},
        {'a':'e', 'b':'f', 'c':5}]

for dicts in list:
    for keys in dicts:
        dicts[keys] = str(dicts[keys])
print(list)
```

Comment: In this case some numbers will be represented in scientific format, which may be undesirable

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this:

```
list = [
   {'a':'p', 'b':2, 'c':'k'},
   {'a':'e', 'b':'f', 'c':5}
]
list = [{key: str(val) for key, val in dict.items()} for dict in list]
print(list)
```

Answer (score 3):

The other solutions all do a one time translation to String, however, that does not help when you can't control if the values are changed back subsequently.

I suggest to subclass dict as such:

```
class StringDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self)
        
    def __getitem__(self, y):
        value_to_string = str(dict.__getitem__(self, y))
        return value_to_string
    
    def get(self, y):
        value_to_string = str(dict.get(self, y))
        return value_to_string
    
    

exampleDict = StringDict()

exampleDict["no_string"] = 123

print(exampleDict["no_string"])
123
print(type(exampleDict["no_string"]))
<class 'str'>
```

This way, the value type is not changed, but upon access it will be converted to String on the fly, guaranteeing it returns a String

Comment: To be honest I dont understand almost none of your code, I guess its a little too much for my level but since i'm just learning and trying to understand as much as I can I've copied your code and what concerns me the most is the last line ```<class 'str'>``` since I've never seen an implementation of those tags in such a way and also the intepreter tells me that this syntax is incorrect... is it?

Comment: Hey, no worries. The last and the third last line can be obmitted. They are just the print outs

Comment: What this code basically does, is it takes the standard dict and overwrites the get functions to always return a string. So when you add the int 123 to the dict and then fetch it, you get '123' without converting it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the dictionary values to strings and then print:

```
list = [{'a':'p', 'b':2, 'c':'k'}, {'a':'e', 'b':'f', 'c':5}]
list = [{str(j): str(i) for i, j in enumerate(d)} for d in list]

for x in list:
    print("the values of b is: " + x['b'])
```

If you just want to print them without changing:

```
for x in list:
    print(f"the values of b is: {x['b']}")
```

Comment: Thanks though in order for the 'f' function to work you have to use double quotes

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out! edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```py
print(f"The value of b is: {x['b']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension :

```
list = [{key: str(dict[key]) for key in dict.keys()} for dict in list]
```